# What the difference between onResize and onResized?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In firemonkey (delphi tokyo), what is the difference between `onResize` and `onResized` event of Tcontrol ? because both are called **AFTER** the control size already changed. And the most important, when to use `onresized` and when to use `onresize`?

from the delphi source code :

```
procedure TControl.SetBounds(X, Y, AWidth, AHeight: Single);
var
  SizeChanged: Boolean;
  Moved: Boolean;
  NeedRepaint: Boolean;
  ReductionSize: Boolean;
begin
  Moved := not (SameValue(X, Position.X, TEpsilon.Position) and SameValue(Y, Position.Y, TEpsilon.Position));
  SizeChanged := not (SameValue(AWidth, Width, TEpsilon.Position) and SameValue(AHeight, Height, TEpsilon.Position));
  if Moved or SizeChanged then
  begin
    ReductionSize := False;
    if SizeChanged then
    begin
      ReductionSize := (FSize.Height > AHeight) or (FSize.Width > AWidth);
      SizeChanged := DoSetSize(FSize, False, AWidth, AHeight, FLastWidth, FLastHeight);
    end;
    NeedRepaint := False;

    if Moved or (SizeChanged and (RotationAngle <> 0)) then
    begin
      if Moved or ReductionSize then
        Repaint;
      FPosition.SetPointNoChange(PointF(X, Y));
      FLeft := FPosition.X;
      FTop := FPosition.Y;
      Inc(FUpdating);
      try
        MatrixChanged(Self);
      finally
        Dec(FUpdating);
      end;
      NeedRepaint := True;
    end;

    if Moved or SizeChanged then
    begin
      if (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
        if (FParentControl <> nil) and not (csDestroying in FParentControl.ComponentState) then
          if (TRectF.Union(BoundsRect, FParentControl.LocalRect) <> FParentControl.LocalRect) then
            FParentControl.RecalcUpdateRect;
      UpdateExplicitBounds;
      UpdateAnchorRules;
      RequestAlign;
    end;

    if not (csLoading in ComponentState) and SizeChanged then
    begin
      UpdateSmallSizeControl;
      Resize;
      if FControls <> nil then
        Realign
      else if HasEffect then
        UpdateEffects;
    end;
    if not (csLoading in ComponentState) and not SizeChanged and Moved then
      Move;
    if not (csLoading in ComponentState) and (Moved or SizeChanged) then
    begin
      RecalcUpdateRect;
      NeedRepaint := True;
    end;
    if not (csLoading in ComponentState) and SizeChanged then
      DoResized;
    if NeedRepaint then
      Repaint;
  end;
end;
```

So it's seam resize and DoResized are both called AFTER the DoSetSize.

Comment: IIRC, in VCL OnResize is called continously *while* the form is being resized, and OnResized is being called when the user releases the mouse button (ends the resize operation). Are you sure that's not how it works in FMX as well?

Comment: If you have an access to full FMX's source code you can investigate this behaviour yourself.

Comment: I am not familar with `FMX`. After inspecting the code I am able to make only such a suggestion: use `OnResized` in most cases. Once `OnResized` event has been fired, you will have control that is *ready to use*. I mean if your control has children they will correctly aligned at the moment when `OnResized` event comes to play.

Comment: As you can see, `OnResize` event is fired *prior* to `Move` and `RecalcUpdateRect` routines (I have no clue for what they are intended for). For example, if you will do some manipulations with children, you can get their wrong placement on the surface of their parent control. Children also might not be carefully repainted, because `NeedRepaint := True;` follows after `OnResize` event. I am often referencing to children because this is usual area of using `OnResizeXXX` events (in my experience, at least). Anyway this is *just* my opinion and you can show yours counterarguments ;)